# Resource resolution fail in executable war that embeds Tomcat 8.5.12

Tags: tomcat, spring-boot

I am getting the below exception with Spring Boot 1.5.6 and Embedded Tomcat 8.5.12:

```
java.io.FileNotFoundException: JAR entry META-INF/ not found in C:\Users\mushtaq\AppData\Local\Temp\jar_cache3257802877193600650.tmp
        at sun.net.www.protocol.jar.JarURLConnection.connect(Unknown Source)
        at sun.net.www.protocol.jar.JarURLConnection.getJarFile(Unknown Source)
        at com.sun.facelets.util.Classpath.search(Classpath.java:69)
        at com.sun.facelets.compiler.TagLibraryConfig.loadImplicit(TagLibraryConfig.java:428)
        at com.sun.facelets.compiler.Compiler.initialize(Compiler.java:87)
        at com.sun.facelets.compiler.Compiler.compile(Compiler.java:104)
        at com.sun.facelets.impl.DefaultFaceletFactory.createFacelet(DefaultFaceletFactory.java:218)
        at com.sun.facelets.impl.DefaultFaceletFactory.getFacelet(DefaultFaceletFactory.java:149)
        at com.sun.facelets.impl.DefaultFaceletFactory.getFacelet(DefaultFaceletFactory.java:100)
        at com.sun.facelets.FaceletViewHandler.buildView(FaceletViewHandler.java:519)
        at com.sun.facelets.FaceletViewHandler.renderView(FaceletViewHandler.java:569)
        at org.ajax4jsf.application.ViewHandlerWrapper.renderView(ViewHandlerWrapper.java:100)
        at org.ajax4jsf.application.AjaxViewHandler.renderView(AjaxViewHandler.java:176)
```

This code is working fine with Embedded Tomcat 8.5.11. Looks like changes in 8.5.12 related to url seperators has broken things.

I have tried to use org.apache.tomcat.util.buf.UriUtil.WAR_SEPARATOR but it is not working.

Comment: What is the question, what are you trying to achieve? Embedding a webserver doesn't look correct.

Comment: I am using spring boot with embedded tomcat 8.5.12 and above. I am using JSF facelets library which is working fine with tomcat version 8.5.11 but failing if i upgrade tomcat 8.5.12 and above.

Comment: Well the error seems to say that a `renderView` function in ajax4jsf expects some file and is not there: `java.io.FileNotFoundException: JAR entry META-INF/`. Did you check if the JSF library is compatible with tomcat 8.5.12? Maybe update the library as well.